# Как отличить событие закрытия Activity от поворота экрана?

Tags: java, android, activity, activity-life-cycle

Как программно отличить событие настоящего **закрытия** `Activity` от промежуточных вызовов `onStop()` и `onDestroy()` при повороте экрана (изменения ориентации экрана)?

Comment: А как у вас происходит настоящее закрытие активити?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод [`boolean isFinishing()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()). Вызывается обычно в `onPause()`.